# Struggling with finding the smallest word in a TRIE

Tags: c, function, trie

Sorry in advance for any English error that I may commit.
I have a school project for university and I have to use a trie to index words and have multiple functions to do multiple things.
I'm programming in C.
I have done a recursive function to find the biggest word in the trie and it is working.
Here's the function:

```
int BiggestWord(ELEMENT *P)
{
    if (!P) return -1;
    int Alt_max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VECTOR; i++)
        Alt_max = Biggest(BiggestWord(P->V[i]), Alt_max);
    return 1 + Alt_max;
}
```

'Biggest' is just a function that returns the biggest value between two values.

Now for the smallest word function. I was thinking about how to do it and tried to do check when the word ended looking for 'NULL' after every Element.
Here is my attempt:

```
int SmallestWord(ELEMENT *P)
{
    if (!P) return -1;
    int Alt_min = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VECTOR; i++)
    {
        if(P->V[i] != NULL)
        {
           SmallestWord(P->V[i]);
           Alt_min++;
        }
    }
    return Alt_min;
}
```

I can't find a way to make it work.
I also thought about trying to, after every word, point that there's the end of a word, and then try to go through every branch of the trie and find the smallest word.
It's my first half-year coding and I'm finding some difficulties trying to learn it.
If anyone could help me by giving me hints or trying to give me clues of where to go I would appreciate it very much since this is a very important project I must finish and do well.

Also, my data structures are the following:

`#define MAX_VECTOR 26` // 26 letters of the Alphabet I'm using

```
typedef struct ELEMENT
{
    int occurrences_word; // this is used for counting number of occurrences of a word
    struct ELEMENT *V[MAX_VECTOR];
} ELEMENT;

typedef struct TRIE
{
    ELEMENT *root_trie;
    int num_words;
} TRIE;
```

Thank you in advance to everyone that contributes to helping me out
Regards

Comment: An element marks the end of a word if and only if all elements of its `V` are `NULL`, is that correct?

Comment: If that's not the case, additional if is needed to count also "inner words" that have occurrences_word > 0, but are not leaf nodes at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no elegant way to do it. The problem is that a `-1` which means a null pointer must be treated differently from a low number which means a short word.

Her is a crude but workable solution:

```
int SmallestWord(ELEMENT *P)
{
  if (!P) return -1; 

  if(P->occurrences_word != 0) // this is the end of a word
    return 1;

  int Alt_min = -1;      
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VECTOR; i++)
    {
      int n = SmallestWord(P->V[i]);
    
      if(n!=-1)
        if(n<Alt_min || Alt_min == -1)
          Alt_min = n;
    }
  return 1 + Alt_min;
}
```

Comment: It's not working :/. It returns me 1 no matter what words I have in the trie.

Comment: @JoãoFaro: Could you give us a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? That is, a full, working program which puts a couple of hard-coded words into the trie and calls the function. This code works when I test it, but I test it with code I wrote, so there must be something different in your code.

Comment: Sorry I have been off for a couple of days because of some other projects I had. I dunno exactly what my issue was but I focused myself on the other functions I had to do and now that the program is almost done I tried out your function again and it works :)))
I guess that the problem was with the occurrences_word.
Thank you very much. I'm looking forward to this project that now can almost declare as finished and I have to deliver it until 13 June :))

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse your solution for biggest (longest - right?) word.

There would be 2 key differences:

- Using a function that returns min instead of max (Smallest instead of Biggest). You can either use a build-in min/max functions or implement your own.
- You need a special case for "-1" that means no result. It used to work fine for longest, since the max function skipped it automatically, but here this -1 will be returned as a shortest word right away, so you need an IF.

Code:

```
int SmallestWord(ELEMENT *P)
{
  if (!P) return -1;
  int Alt_min = 1000000000;
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VECTOR; i++) {
    int candidate = SmallestWord(P->V[i]);
    if (candidate != -1)
      Alt_min = min(candidate, Alt_min);
  }
  return 1 + Alt_min;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: Not tested. You might need to add a condition for words that are prefixes of other words. So that if occurrences_word is positive, count that node as a candidate word too.

Comment: I thought of that and tried a similar approach before.
I made a function of 'Smallest' and tried your code but it doesn't work :/.
It just returns me 1 no matter the words I have on the trie.
It literally just adds 1 to Alt_min.
I understood your approach but I can't understand why it doesn't work as well ://

Comment: Right, alt min needs to be set to something very large first.

Comment: Neither of those answer work ://. Both functions always return 1 no matter what words I have on the trie.